# Rotating a point around a circle

Tags: math, lua, trigonometry

I am trying to make a "rotating minimap" of sorts for a "game", of sorts, I am having two sets of coordinates for two players, one would be the player and the other the target and also the direction the player is facing relative to the plane.
They are located in a 2d plane with each having their coordinates (eg. A(56.25, 23.44), B(50.17, 33.57)).

So, I want to basically turn a static "minimap" into a rotating one by hopefully having the player (A) be the center, an anchor around which B would rotate according to the direction the player is facing

In mathematical(?) terms this would mean I want to rotate point B around a circle whose center is point A by an angle
(I am in no means an expert or even adept in either field, I have taught myself everything I know so take my definitions and terms with a grain of salt)

[Kind of a basic idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxaoG.png); Where A is the player or point of origin, B the target or point to be moved and B' is the point it would be moved to. The line going through B' would be the direction the player is facing at the given angle alpha

This point **has** been asked around these forums and, I guess, solved, I **have** seen these and I do not fully understand them nor do they solve my issue

Namely, some posts say the formulae for B'(X, Y) would be `X = hyp * cos(a)` (where a is angle and hyp hypotenuse) and `Y = hyp * sin(a)` but for *unknown*(?) reasons this made my B' go wild also it was inapplicable if A and B were on the same axis (I do not understand how it works nor why it doesn't)

Another post said the formulae should be `X = Ax * cos(a) - Ay * sin(a)` and `Y = Ay * cos(a) - Ax * sin(a)`; This, sadly, did not work either so in the end I do not understand why or how either of these work and why neither do not work, the angle has been given in both degrees and radians

This is the code I have used for testing (before implementing into my idea):

```lua
local pX, pY, fX, fY = 10, 20, 10, 40
local playerA = 45
local X, Y = fX - pX, fY - pY
local hyp = math.sqrt((X ^ 2) + (Y ^ 2))
local X2, Y2 = hyp * math.cos(playerA), hyp * math.sin(playerA)
print(X2, Y2, hyp)
```

(Where the player's coordinates would be pX and pY, target's fX and fY, the radius or hypotenuse hyp and angle playerA) And just drawing the resulting coordinates with the expected angle, things mostly seemed off

Hopefully, I explained the issue and my work so far well enough, thank you for reading thus far and giving it a thought!

Edit: I **have** solved my issue by converting the target's pair of coordinates to polar, adding an angle I want it to move by and converting back to cartesian, this is looking promising for now but still the question above is bothering me; For anyone curious or looking for alike answer, this "solution" was tested like this:

```lua
local x, y = 20, 20
local hyp = math.sqrt((x ^ 2) + (y ^ 2))
local a = math.atan(y / x)
print(hyp, math.deg(a))
a = a + math.rad(135)
local x2 = hyp * math.cos(a)
local y2 = hyp * math.sin(a)
print("(" .. x2 .. ", " .. y2 .. ")")
local hyp = math.sqrt((x2 ^ 2) + (y2 ^ 2))
local a = math.atan(y2 / x2)
print(hyp, math.deg(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly right, but some corrections are needed: lua trig. functions work with radians arguments, so you have to transform 45 degrees into radians (I gave two ways). And your calculated positions are relative to player, so for absolute coordinates you have to add player's ones:

```
local pX, pY, fX, fY = 10, 20, 10, 40

local playerA = 45 * math.Pi / 180
  or
local playerA  = math.rad(45)

local X, Y = fX - pX, fY - pY
local hyp = math.sqrt((X ^ 2) + (Y ^ 2))

local X2, Y2 = pX + hyp * math.cos(playerA), pY + hyp * math.sin(playerA)

print(X2, Y2, hyp)
```

Comment: This has been done, maybe I forgot to mention it, have tried both in degrees and radians but neither gave reliable results; Shouldn't it also be simpler if they were just relative to the player? Having the player at 0,0 and them at whatever

Comment: Is `X ^ 2` equal to squared X in Lua, not binary xor? Provide simple data to your function and check result of every string. For example, X=6,Y=8, angle=45 should give hyp 10 and final coordinates 7.071

Comment: I have done as you said, it returned `5.2532198881773 8.5090352453412 10` as in (5.25, 8.5) with hyp 10 which does not look like what it should be, also have tried with (10, 10) and angle of 90, returned `-6.3367178487143    12.643022063802 14.142135623731`; Also I have used X *X instead of X ^ 2 (results were the same) just to be sure

Comment: Reason is simple - you are using **45 radians** rather than degrees (cos(45 radians) = 0.52532198881773)).  Just apply my correction.

Comment: You are completely correct with that and I have done some testing and plotting, I do not know why it works but it seems to not give *correct* or **desired** results for degrees > 90 or < 0 (not that it would ever be <0)

Comment: And what are results for these angles (for example, 135, 180, 270, -90)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5fgeyXy
I have tested it with the values you gave me as well as some others with the code you have written up there

Edit: In all these the coordinates are as was first written, A(10, 20) and B(10, 40)

Comment: Now I don't know what you really need. Absolute angle? Relative angle? Provided code sets coordinates of target at absolute angle (playerA) independently on previous target coordinates.

Comment: [ideone code](https://ideone.com/JzeveF) gives right results for absolute angles 45, -45,135, and 270 degrees. But your addition with `adding an angle I want it to move` is ANOTHER problem - relative angles.

Comment: Well, yes, I want to add an angle to the one I have, if you look at the edit you might understand better - done with polar coordinates, adding an angle to the angle of the point to X axis or the Y axis whichever is goes (as is shown on original picture with moving B by alpha - adding 45 to 0)